takes no arguments in FSM step
One-step FSM
Error: Town() takes no arguments
@weather_router.message(Command("weather"))
class Town(StatesGroup):
    town = State()
async def town(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f"{message.from_user.first_name}, введи город")
    await state.set_state(Town.town)
async def townn(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f"Ваш город\n{message.text}")

I want bot to handle users “town” and send it him back by text message using FSM


remove "Town" states group from under decorator,
because it decorates a group of states, not a message handler
decorate "townn" function with state filter: @weather_router.message(Town.town)
add await state.clear() to "townn" function to clear FSM context

code:
class Town(StatesGroup):
    town = State()

@weather_router.message(Command('weather'))
async def town(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Town.town)

    await message.answer(f"{message.from_user.first_name}, введи город")

@weather_router.message(Town.town)
async def townn(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f"Ваш город\n{message.text}")

    await state.clear()

